# How can I change char array to int using C?

Tags: c

i am studying C now, and I am parsing a raw registry file and read it.

i have some problem now,

```
000011E0    00 00 00 00 60 01 00 00 B9 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000011F0    20 C0 26 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 
00001200    10 FC 00 00 FF FF FF FF 4C 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
this is hex value of REGISTRY file.

fseek(fp,0x11F0,SEEK_SET);

char tmp[4];
int now = ftell(fp);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
    tmp[i] = fgetc(fp);
    }
```

I made this tmp array, but I need 0x0026c020.
how can I change this array to that value? or please suggest me better algorithm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for a fact that the value is stored with the same endianness as the host OS architecture, you can just do:

```
int value = *(int *)tmp;
```

However, you should *not* read the bytes in backwards order, as you do here -- that alters the endianness and will result in an incorrect value.  Try this:

```
int value;
if (fread(&value, sizeof(value), 1, fp) != 1) {
    /* Could not read, handle error. */
}

/* value is set, inspect it */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about if endian is different?

Comment: Then you need to first determine two things: what is the endianness of the data, and what is the endianness of the host?  If one is big and one is little, do a byte-swap.  The standard 4-byte swap idiom is: `value = ((value & 0xffu) << 24) | ((value & 0xff00u) << 8) | ((value & 0xff0000u) >> 8) | ((value & 0xff000000u) >> 24);`

Comment: Or instead of making your own functions, when you create the array, use the network functions htonl() and when you read the array use ntohl()/  This is guaranteed to work whether the endian matches or not and will do nothing if you are on a network order/big endian system (not x86). Well, I guess you don't write the values, but you can still use ntohl() or friends when reading

Comment: @SethRobertson But in this case, the storage looks to be little-endian -- *not* network order.  htonl/ntohl will swap on little-endian and won't swap on big-endian -- exactly the opposite of what the OP may need.  And, likely, the storage in the registry *is* dependent on the host CPU and so no swapping should be necessary in either case.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string into integer there are already available functions one such function is 
strtoul().

you can use standard strtoul() function to convert string into integer values.