# What's the easiest way to convert from binary file to a C integer?

Tags: c

I have a binary file which contains 4 bytes representing an integer number. I want to read this value and store it into an `int` variable in C. Is it possible?

The number that I have is `176` which is written like this `...°` into the binary file, and if I take the hexadecimal it is `0x00 0x00 0x00 0xb0` and that is fine.

But I need to get the `176` into an `int` variable in C. I hope that I made myself clear.

Thank you!

UPDATE:
I read the file into a `uint8_t` array.
So now I have `uint8_t* my_value` containing the 4 bytes that I read.
If I write

```
int hvalue = my_value[3];
```

I get `176`, and it works fine but it looks like it's not a good thing to do (because this is a lucky case where `176` stays in the 1 byte, but if I have a bigger number that needs 2 or 3 bytes this is not going to work anymore)..
I'm sorry but I have troubles explaining myself...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change char array to int using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515966/how-can-i-change-char-array-to-int-using-c)

Comment: Just do a binary read.  You may have to do byteswaps depending on the endianess of the data and the target machine.

Comment: Don't describe your code but show it.

Comment: Show more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a little hacky because it's not going to work for a value like

```
0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b
```

Your problem is basically that of big-endian to native-endian (little or big) conversion.

Under POSIX, the `ntohl` (Network To Host, Long) function from `<arpa/inet.h>` handles that for 32-bit numbers.

A solution based on `ntohl` would be to `memcpy`/read the bytes into an `uint32_t` and then apply `ntohl` to it:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int32_t getint32(unsigned char *bytes)
{
    int32_t r;
    memcpy(&r,bytes,sizeof(r));
    return (int32_t)ntohl(r);
}
```

In terms of something more basic, you'd read into an `uint32_t`/`int32_t` and then reverse the bytes iff (and only if) your machine's endianness wasn't big-endian (this is what the `ntoh*` functions (typically inline functions) do + they'll typically do the byte reversion (if it's needed) with a `bswap` intrinsic).

You can also compose the number manaually from the octets:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t getint32_(unsigned char *bytes)
{
    uint32_t r = 
    ((uint32_t)bytes[0]<<24)|
    ((uint32_t)bytes[1]<<16)|
    ((uint32_t)bytes[2]<<8)|
    ((uint32_t)bytes[3]<<0);
    return (int32_t)r;
}
```

Gcc >= 5 and clang >= 5 (but not older versions) are capable of pattern matching the above into a bswap instruction, so you don't really need `htonl` (or and explicit `__builtin_bswap`) to get compact/efficent endian-converting code on those (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/wBYzuS).

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need to do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
int32_t thevalue;    // declare a 32 bit int, int may have a different size from 4
                     // on your platform

FILE *file = fopen("thefile", "rb");   // open file in binary mode
if (file != NULL)
{
  fread(&theValue, sizeof(thevalue), 1, file);
  fclose(file);
}
```

You might need to handle [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) though.